# Name Error while using if statements - Python 2.7

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop

I'm currently working on a project which acts as an airline reservation booking system.  As of right now I'm having an issue with calculating and displaying a subtotal which was calculated inside of an if elif else loop statement, if that makes sense.

For example, I currently need to calculate the subtotal of the seats and luggage.  Below is my code:

```
user_people = int(raw_input("Welcome to Ramirez Airlines!  How many people will be flying?"))
user_seating = str(raw_input("Perfect!  Now what type of seating would your party prefer?"))
user_luggage = int(raw_input("Thanks.  Now for your luggage, how many bags would you like to check in?"))
user_frequent = str(raw_input("Got it.  Is anyone in your party a frequent flyer with us?"))
user_continue = str(raw_input("Your reservation was submitted successfully.  Would you like to do another?"))
luggage_total = user_luggage * 50

print luggage_total + seats_total
```

As I said above I'm trying to add the total price for the number of plane tickets reserved based on which class the user chose (economy, business and first class) and the total amount of the required luggage needed to be checked in (x amount & $50).

This is the error I am receiving when executing the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cory/Desktop/Project 1.py", line 26, in <module>
    print luggage_total + seats_total
NameError: name 'seats_total' is not defined
```

How do I go about defining seats_total outside of the if-elif-else statements?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a string rather than a variable:

```
if user_seating == 'economy':
```

The way you have it, Python is looking for an actual variable named `economy` declared in your code (which there isn't as the `NameError` tells you).

Comment: This was so simple, can't believe I missed it.  Thanks so much!  If I have another question pertaining to this same project, do I keep making comments on this thread or do I post a new question entirely?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CoryRamirez It's best to make a new question (I think that's the general policy around here). Anyway, it's also better for you; very few people from here on out are likely to come here, whereas new and unanswered questions are given attention immediately.

Answer (score 2):

`economy` and `business` are being treated as variables. You must make them strings for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

As the message says: you never defined the variable `economy`.  It appears you meant to compare `user_seating` to the *string value* `economy`; if that is the case, you need to enclose it in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put economy inside quotes i.e.

```
if user_seating == 'economy':
seats_total = user_people * 916
print seats_total
```

and of course do that for your other if statements as well. You should also think about making the user input lowercase before checking for equality.